# image does not fit in the image view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I am making an project in swift there is an image view and I am taking an image from gallery when I set the image in the image view the image does not match with the width and height of image view. overtime the image width and height is small than the image view
here is the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "ImageTVCell"
        index=indexPath.row
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ImageTVCell
       // cell?.imageView?.clipsToBounds=true
        cell?.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        cell?.imageView?.image=imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/

Comment: Try `.scaleAspectFill`

Comment: I try this but its not work

Answer (score 2):

Use `.aspectfill` and set `clipsToBounds` to `true`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "ImageTVCell"
        index=indexPath.row
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ImageTVCell
        cell?.imageView?.clipsToBounds=true
        cell?.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        cell?.imageView?.image=imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell?.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

in your code is fitting image size in your imageview. You should use,

```
cell?.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
```

Also makes clipsToBounds=true.

For better understanding of Imageview content modes visit
http://blogs.innovationm.com/image-handling-in-ios/